# How can I return a pointer to registers with different types

Tags: c, embedded, pic, pic24

I would like to write a function which returns a pointer to either one of two special function registers (SFRs). These SFRs have different types, but their types are identical except for their names:

```
#define SFRxType SFR0Type

typedef struct SFR0Type {
    union {
        struct {
            uint16_t var0;
            uint16_t var1;
        };
        struct {
            uint32_t var;
        };
    };
} SFR0Type;
extern volatile SFR0Type SFR0 __attribute__((__sfr__));

typedef struct SFR1Type {
    union {
        struct {
            uint16_t var0;
            uint16_t var1;
        };
        struct {
            uint32_t var;
        };
    };
} SFR1Type;
extern volatile SFR1Type SFR1 __attribute__((__sfr__));
```

(The `__sfr__` attribute tells the compiler the variable address is set by the linker script.)

These typedefs reside in a header I do not own, so I cannot change them.

My function looks like this:

```
static volatile SFRxType* get_sfr_ptr(uint16_t select) {
    return select ? &SFR1 : &SFR0;
}
```

However, this produces a compiler warning: `warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression`.

How can I write a function like this without generating a warning, given the above constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?:` isn't really suitable since it requires the 2nd and 3rd operands to be of types that are either compatible or can be made compatible by implicit conversion. If using that operator you have to cast the operand which isn't of the correct type and from there dive down into this "language lawyer" rabbit hole (C17 6.5.15):

> Furthermore, if both operands are pointers to compatible types or to differently qualified versions of compatible types, the result type is a pointer to an appropriately qualified version of the composite type;

Unfortunately these 2 structs here are *not* compatible because someone had the bad idea to use different struct tags for them. If not for those otherwise 100% superfluous tags, they would have been compatible even if `typedef` names were different.

So the best option is probably to forget all about implicit conversions and composite types and instead use `if`. Keep it simple. And do explicit casts no matter which type that's picked:

```c
static volatile SFRxType* get_sfr_ptr(uint16_t select) {
    if(select != 0)
      return (volatile SFRxType*)&STF1;

    return (volatile SFRxType*)&STF0;
}
```

But please note that this returned pointer will still have to get cast to its correct type before use - again because the structs are not compatible.

Comment: Also if the compiler used is some flavour of the infamous MPLAB, then I would strongly advise against relying on exotic detailed rules of C, because those compilers have poor C conformance.

Comment: Yes, the compiler is xc16, unfortunately.

Comment: Does the structs being incompatible mean I can't do this: `volatile SFRxType* const sfr_ptr = get_sfr_ptr(select)`? I don't know at compile-time which SFR will be selected; that's why I'm trying to write this function.

Comment: @abessman It is the same pointer type in that example. C allows wild and crazy pointer casts between all manner of incompatible types. The actual problem appears when you de-reference the struct/access the members - in case you access one struct using the wrong struct type, then that's undefined behavior. Embedded system compilers usually don't implement strict aliasing optimizations which would be a risk, but regardless it is better to not write code containing undefined behavior. Ideally skip this badly designed register map and write your own one.

Answer (score 2):

Two options are:

1. Change `return select ? &SFR1 : &SFR0;` to `return select ? (volatile SFRxType *) &SFR1 : &SFR0;`. The caller will be responsible for casting the returned pointer to its correct type.
2. Change the declaration of `get_sfr_ptr` to `static void *get_sf_ptr(uint16_t select)` and change the `return` statement to `return select ? (volatile void *) &SFR1 : (volatile void *) &SFR0;`. The caller will be responsible for using the returned pointer as its correct type.

Comment: SFR0 is of type `volatile SFR1Type` so either this is a typo in the question or they are both of the same type. As it stands, the cast proposed here actually breaks the code, since operand 2 and 3 of `?:` can't be of different pointer types.

Comment: @Lundin: It has to be a typo or they would not have gotten the reported compiler message.